# multi image select and print selected images using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel-5

i have image set div tag like below:

```js
function printImg() {
  pwin = window.open(document.getElementById("mainImg").src,"_blank");
  window.print();
}
$(function () {
    $("#gallery > img").click(function () {
        if ($(this).data('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).data('selected', false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).data('selected', true);
    }
    });
    var selectedImageArray = [];
$('#gallery > img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('selected')) {
        selectedImageArray.print(this);
    }
});
 window.onafterprint = function(){
      window.location.reload(true);
 }

});
```

```css
img.selected {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery">
<img name=imgqr[] id="mainImg" src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(180)->generate($user->emp_code[$i])) !!} " width="100"; height="80"; >{{$user->emp_first_name}}&nbsp;{{$user->emp_last_name}}&nbsp;{{!!($user->dpt_name)!!}}</td></tr>                             
 </div>
<input  class="printMe" type="button" onclick="printImg()" value="printMe" />
```

i need to select image when user click on it, i added the script for this and it working, but  i click print button it doesnt print qrcode image ,in meantime is printing whole page.

I also need check if image is selected and pass through array value to print seleted images +data name.

Comment: have you tried to config the **Page Setup** for printing ?

Comment: i think i didn't @MohsenNewtoa

Comment: can you explain it more clearly @MohsenNewtoa

Comment: why do you not use qrCode library instead of PNG ?

Comment: i already used qr code library(simple qrcode) and png is only generate png image that is why i used it @MohsenNewtoa

Answer (score 0):

**Window.print() will always print the entire current window.** You could bypass this by adding the selected images to a pop up and then print that pop up.

```
popup = window.open();
popup.document.write("imagehtml");
popup.focus(); //required for IE
popup.print();
```

You can do this one window for one photo but ofcourse you can also add multiple photo's to one screen and then print it.

Your second question asks for an array with the selected images. Because you use jQuery you can just get them by

```
allSelectedImages = $('.selected');
```

You can loop that array en call the function .data() on it to get all data attributes!

Hope this helps!

Comment: it doesn't work for me ,the 1st answer you mentioned ,print nothing and the 2nd one can explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling print on the main window, call print from the window you opened

```
function printImg() {
  pwin = window.open(document.getElementById("mainImg").src,"_blank");
  pwin.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think if there is any problem with your codes,

try this and let me know

***Firefox :***

[image]

---

***Google Chrome:***

[image]

Comment: hi,this is not i'm looking for ,i think i'm not described very well. i want select particular image using multi select or something like that